# Problem using signalr for chat application flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, signalr, signalr.client, dart-null-safety

I had made a whole chat application using signalr as a socket with the online and offline facility. I am facing a few problems,

- Signalr connection is always time out after some time, to overcome that I had condition if hubconnection is not connected then create new hubconnection (onResume app), but still it get **hubconnection._callback** got increased when sending message and not moving to server side socket. Again need to refresh whole app.

Can someone tell me whether this is problem because there are lot of operations going on and so signalr loses its connection as flutter is single thread and it cannot handle much? or **should I use Isolate or inherit widget**.

Summary problem:

I cannot send message in chat after sometime. It stores all message in **hubconnection._callback** and not going for server.

Is anything better solution to keep alive in both Android+iOS.

I had used https://pub.dev/packages/signalr_netcore package.

Please do not mention about firebase.

Any other logic suggestion is appreciable.
Thank you.

Comment: is it disconnecting on background? like when the app is in background?

Comment: Yes it gets disconnect when it is in background....and also sometimes when connected all invokes goes in hubconnection._callback(this goes increasing when sending message too) it should be 0 when it is properly working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been using a different package, https://pub.dev/packages/signalr_core, which works fine without any particular issues what I have observed at the moment.

I'm only running about 10 listeners simultaneously, not sure if that is more or less than you. In the package I'm running you can establish connection with automatic reconnect. It looks like this:

```
HubConnectionBuilder().withAutomaticReconnect().withUrl(....)
```

It seems like your package have the same functionality... Have you tried that?

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I had use exactly same....just day before signalr_core and I had changed to signalr_netcore. As you suggested all was there

Comment: But thing is I have online and offline functionality and it should remain connected but it is not after some time. How you manage for so long in android as well as iOS? Can you tell me?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. And what is "for so long"? How long is that?

Comment: My question is preety simple, when app is in background after sometime it loses handshake. And when we resume(lifecycle) app....I am unable to send chat to server as it is not connected. What you do to make connections for so long? Have you use isolate? Or something else for chat application?

Comment: When app is in background, it is fine for me that it disconnects. I reconnect and listen to groups etc when I resume. To catch up on data that was sent over signalr while being disconnected is fetched using other methods.

Comment: Yeah I am doing exactly same. How you reconnect? I had used exactly same as you told in above paragraph automatic reconnect. Will you able to show demo piece of code, About your implementation of signalr? It will be little helpful may be I am doing some wrong. I am following this when user disconnect and again (resume app) it is making new object of hubconnectionbuilder everytime only when user is not connected and also added method ping every 20 seconds but after long time timer also not not working.

Comment: I cannot share the code. But here is the jest of it.. I have a class defined as a lazy singleton. That class holds a HubConnection. The constructor sets up the hubconnection with automatic reconnect. Important is to override the dispose method of the class to stop the hubConnection when appropriate. I also have a method to check that the connection state is not disconnected before trying to join a group. If I am disconnected, then I start the connection again.

Comment: Okay. One last question will it be solved using lazy singleton and have you put something which keeps alive like ping and also have you used isolate? Because my main aim is chatting application should work throughout without stop. But current scenario is it stops after sometimes. Thank you for your tips and you can suggest some more I will be thank ful.

Comment: I'm using lazy singleton just to be sure that I use the same instance throughout my app and not creating a bunch of connections where I actually want a single instance. No extra keep-alives. No isolates. I'm not using signalr to notify user if app is terminated or in background.

Comment: Ok to notify there is notification right? Well thanks for the explanation.  I actually used singleton too but only problem is it is filling hubconnection._callback after sometime which means it is just storing and not sending to server. This is the only problem in singleton. Restarting everything works well. Anyways thanks alot.